# Can you recharge a 12V 7Ah sealed lead acid battery that falls below 10V?

Tags: battery-charging

Just wondering what will happen to the battery if it falls below 10V. Is it still rechargeable, or is a new battery required?

Comment: Depends for how long is has stayed at 10 V. Short while? No problem. Weeks, it’s probably degraded.

Comment: thanks for your information. At what stage or voltage the battery will truly be dead. dead as in cannot be recharged anymore. I was wondering if it falls even lower at 5V but within a few days ,will it still be rechargeable anymore? Also once again, at what stage will it truly be dead?

Comment: the voltage you read is at the terminals.  whether the battery is dead depends on the state of the lead within.  Making generalizations for all batteries is not good.  they have battery testers for automotive batteries in a lot of places... these charge and discharge the battery to check the actual function.  If the battery does not function, we call it "dead"

Comment: @Abel Thanks for your input. I've read some comments online that seems to generalize the battery conditions. Therefore, I wanted to further understand about the limitations of a working battery. At least ,a cut off point to where they are considered "dead".

Comment: 12 V is six cell battery. Minimum voltage for lead-acid is 1.1-1.2 V.

Comment: 5 V and a few days will permanently degrade the battery. If it’s still usable despite higher self discharge and lower capacity is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to know for sure is to try and charge the battery. If it accepts and keeps a charge, it's still functional. In general, lead-acid batteries are quite tame and forgiving when it comes to over-discharging (and also, to a limited extend, over-charging).

The battery won't ignite or explode when it's damaged by over-discharging, unlike Li-Ion batteries, so you can just go ahead and try to charge it.

If the battery is dead, its voltage will drop rapidly as soon as you connect a load.